# How do I use std::is_same_v in a using statement?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
using IsInt = std::is_same<T, int>::value;

template<class SrcType, class DstType>
constexpr DstType As(SrcType val) {
  if constexpr (IsInt<SrcType>) return val;
}
```

This code compiles fine with C++17 but if I use std::is_same_v<...> instead of std::is_same<...>::value, then the GCC complains:

> error: 'std::is_same_v<_Tp, _Up>' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

I'm guessing the error is due to the fact that std::is_same_v is declared constexpr. How can I fix it (while maintaining the type alias)?

Comment: Not sure the duplicate is relevant here. Isn't the problem that `using` is for _type_ aliases but `std::is_same<T, int>::value` is a `bool` value? Your version [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/Pcqe3b7h9) compile for me. And if I change `IsInt` from a `using` to `inline constexpr bool` [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/n6z9bxeYf), it works with `is_same::value` and `is_same_v`

Comment: @NathanPierson, Could be that the OP is compiling with C++20 even though it says C++17, since C++20 removed the need for `typename` there. Of course instantiating that template will still run into the same problem. As for the duplicate, yeah, it doesn't _look_ relevant to me.

Comment: I was mistaken, it doesn't compile. But it does with your fix! Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: `::value` means it's a... value! And not a type. You might want `template<typename T> using IsInt = std::is_same<T, int>;`. And a possible value instantiation of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the sample code doesn't compile.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using IsInt = std::is_same<T, int>::value;
```

The `using` declaration here is for type aliases. In C++17, it would have to be

```cpp
template<typename T>
using IsInt = typename std::is_same<T, int>::value;
```

However, this is incorrect, because `std::is_same<T, int>::value` *isn't* a type, it's a value, and we want `IsInt` to be a value as well.

(In C++20, because only typenames are syntactically correct for the right hand side of this kind of `using` expression, the use of the `typename` keyword is no longer required here, but it's still creating a type alias, which is not what's intended.)

So what we actually want is the same sort of helper that C++17 uses for its `_v` convenience members:

```cpp
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool IsInt = std::is_same<T, int>::value;
```

The following also works:

```cpp
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool IsInt = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
```

`inline` assuming that this lives in a header and we want to use this same definition in multiple translation units, `constexpr` because it's known at compile time and this lets us use it in `if constexpr` or other purposes.